# Hiding Standard fields from the Record creation window - Napili Template

Tags: community, napili, create-records, fls

Seems straight forward: Field Level Security to hide the fields, but this seems like, we cannot make disable the Read permission(as it always defaults to checked): Created By, Last Modified By, Record's Unique Identifier field(Auto Number), Record Type and Owner' on the Record creation dialog window in the Napili template.

I know most of these fields will get values after the record creation, but why they are displaying with literally no values on the creation form? Can we hide/disable from the layout? That way Community users tends to see only the necessary input fields.

NOTE: I need to have these fields on the page layout as the supervisor(Salesforce user license user) must have access to these fields for obvious reasons.

Sample screenshots:

Record creation window - Napili template:
[image]

Permission set where I have the FLS:

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you are talking about the standard lightning system, i can suggest 2 options: ( 1 ) move those fields down on the page layout so the users are less affected. (2) create 2 layouts and 2 profiles, one where you remove those system fields, and another dedicated to the supervisor! I don't know if is a solution, but is the best that i can figure out with point and click.

Comment: Editing your post to get more attention is inappropriate behavior and may lead to undesirable consequences. The correct way to draw additional attention to a post is by **[placing a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)**.

Comment: My sincere apologies for that. I really wanted to seek someone's attention/suggestion on fixing this. Nothing more than that. I really appreciate SFSE for all the support at my hard times.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create custom Lightning Cowith mponent where you will have form for record create,
2. 2 different profile and 2 layout
3. You can inspect in development mode css class or tag - and prepare properly css selector with attribute display:none; and paste it to comunity builder ->

for example - in my standard layout for Account, contact, Case working good - test with for example: background-color: red;

```
    body > div.DESKTOP.uiPanelManager2.onePanelManager.siteforcePanelManager.siteforcePanelsContainer > div > div.panel.slds-modal.slds-fade-in-open > div > div.modal-body.scrollable.slds-modal__content.slds-p-around--medium > div > div > div.test-id__record-layout-container.riseTransitionEnabled > div > div:nth-child(4) {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. But this is completely a custom path, which I am not headed to. As I've already mentioned in my question, this is a standard salesforce functionality(creating a record from 'New' button). Can't we just hide the standard fields from the Community user's visibility? If I am missing something at the field levels access, please suggest me something that works. Thanks.